# How to write code to catch null exception in python

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, null

I have below code, which I want to write in a way so that it catches proper exception.

```
  def MyFunction(MyArg1, MyArg2):

     if not MyArg2:
          raise ?Error?
```

I think it will be type error but I need the exception to be more explicit

Comment: You mean using `if key in response`?

Comment: I mean if no loadStartTime or loadEndTime or renditionBuilderStart or renditionBuilderEnd time is not present . Ho to handle this scenario

Comment: use an `if` statement to check whether the keys exist. If they don't then you have to decide whether to do something else or nothing at all.

Comment: @JanWilamowski can you put a code for the above

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is. As it stands, it looks like you're simply asking us to do your work. That is not what StackOverflow is for. If you have never used an `if` statement I recommend you start out with a basic Python tutorial.

Comment: @JanWilamowski Its not like that, I have made the changes wanted to validate as I am beginer may be I am bit shy at showing my code nothing else. you can see the updated changes in the answer section of this

Comment: Please don't post your code as an answer. It is part of the question so go ahead and [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71688201/edit) it in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try this

```py
if key is None:
    raise TypeError
```

or

```py
if key is None:
    print("There is no key.")
```

Comment: Can you show how to write this in the above code snipent

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have trieD

```
    if MyArg2 is None:
    raise TypeError
```

Comment: You should check if all of the keys are in `response`, not if it is None (which is never the case)